# SQL query, display people with most properties

Tags: mysql

so I'm having trouble working this out:

I need to display the name and telephone number of the people who own the most properties from  these tables:

owners:

```
ownerno | fname | lname | telno 
_________________________________
B6      | John  | g     | 67869
_________________________________
B5      | Tom   | f     | 46876
_________________________________
B4      | Sally | s     | 23456
_________________________________
B3      | Ann   | a     | 23786
```

Propertyowned:

```
propertyno | ownerno 
_____________________
BH5        | B6
_____________________
BG6        | B5
_____________________
BJ7        | B6
_____________________
BF5        | B5
_____________________
BD4        | B4
```

Hope you can help me out
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT 
    count(p.propertyno) as numproperties, 
    o.fcname, 
    o.lname, o.telno
FROM 
    property p, 
    owner o 
WHERE 
    o.ownerno = p.ownerno 
GROUP BY 
    o.ownerno
ORDER BY
    numproperties desc
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  o.fname,
  o.lname,
  o.telno,
  count(p.propertyno) as property_count
FROM
  owners o
  INNER JOIN
  Propertyowned p
    ON p.ownerno = o.ownerno
GROUP BY
  o.fname,
  o.lname,
  o.telno
ORDER BY 
  count(p.propertyno) DESC
```